# Script fields in nested objects specificaly geo_shapes

Tags: elasticsearch

Part of my document mapping consisits of the mapping below

```
       "locations": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "point": {
              "type": "geo_shape",
              "tree": "quadtree",
              "precision": "100m"
            }
          }
        }
```

When I attempt to issue a `script_field` as part of a query Elasticsearch is returning an error

`failed to run inline script [doc['locations.point'].distanceInMiles(53.4791,-2.2441)] using lang [groovy]`

With a reason of:

`failed to find field data builder for field locations.point, and type geo_shape`

I'm assuming this is because the field is nested (it has a few (geo) `points` inside the field and the search matches on any one of them, however as it's nested the context of the path `locations.point` is obviously wrong, it needs to be something like `locations.point[10]` (for the 11th one perhaps - this is dependant on the context of the matched item in the query).

So, does anyone know a way to perform this properly? Is there a special operator I can tell the script so that it knows it needs to look at the matched `point` from the field?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's actually not possible to do this with `geo_shape`'s